# Plot the number of instances in first column with respect to second column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this table in excel which I am trying to analyze. I am not able to plot the number of S and D (in column 3) according to months (in Col4). I am plotting the number of S and D in col3 using the following. But how to plot the number of S & D according to the months. How to do that?

I would like to get two line plots showing the number of S and D respectively with the corresponding months on the X-axis.

```
#to plot the number of S and D in col3

df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\data.csv', usecols = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'])
df['Col4'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col4'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date
df.head()

df1 = df[['Col3']].copy()
my_dict = df1['Col3'].value_counts().to_dict()  
myList = my_dict.items()
x, y = zip(*myList) 
plt.bar(x, y, color = "tomato")
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Outcome')
plt.show() 


    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   Y   MA  S   2/2/2022
1   N   YJ  D   4/25/2022
2   N   YJ  D   3/11/2022
3   N   YJ  D   4/28/2022
4   Y   YJ  D   4/21/2022
5   N   YJ  D   4/21/2022
6   Y   WE  D   5/25/2022
7   Y   WE  S   5/7/2022
8   N   WE  D   3/30/2022
9   N   PR  D   3/22/2022
10  Y   PR  S   3/22/2022
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what the OP wants given the data frame as posted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'Col2': ['MA', 'YJ', 'YJ', 'YJ', 'YJ', 'YJ', 'WE', 'WE', 'WE', 'PR', 'PR'],
                   'Col3': ['S', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'S', 'D', 'D', 'S'],
                   'Col4': ['2/2/2022', '4/25/2022', '3/11/2022', '4/28/2022', '4/21/2022',
                            '4/21/2022', '5/25/2022', '5/7/2022',  '3/30/2022', '3/22/2022', '3/22/2022']})
```

1. First extract the month from the dates in `Col4` (and sort ascending by month):

```
df.loc[:, 'Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Col4).dt.month
df = df.sort_values('Month', ascending=True)
    Col1 Col2 Col3       Col4  Month
 0     Y   MA    S   2/2/2022      2
 2     N   YJ    D  3/11/2022      3
 8     N   WE    D  3/30/2022      3
 9     N   PR    D  3/22/2022      3
 10    Y   PR    S  3/22/2022      3
 1     N   YJ    D  4/25/2022      4
 3     N   YJ    D  4/28/2022      4
 4     Y   YJ    D  4/21/2022      4
 5     N   YJ    D  4/21/2022      4
 6     Y   WE    D  5/25/2022      5
 7     Y   WE    S   5/7/2022      5
```

2. Create a pivot table with `Month` as the index, the values of `Col3` (i.e., `S` and `D`) as columns, and counts as the cell values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Col3'])\
        .size()\
        .unstack(fill_value=0)\
        .reset_index()
 Col3  Month  D  S
 0         2  0  1
 1         3  3  1
 2         4  4  0
 3         5  1  1
```

3. Plot the results

```
plt.plot(df1.Month, df1.D, label='D')
plt.plot(df1.Month, df1.S, label='S')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As a followup, I am trying to find the change in the number of S and D per month. y= (df1["S"])
z= (df1["D"])


for i in range(len(y)):
    rate_y=my_y(i)-my_y(i-1)
    rate_z=my_z(i)-my_z(i-1)

Comment: You should look at `pandas.DataFrame.diff` and `pandas.Series.diff`. So, `rate_y = df1.S.diff(periods=1)` (same for `z`) for forward difference of one period. In general, the SO community encourages you to post any followup as additional questions if you want an answer. This is so that others can benefit from searching for questions and answers.